# C# HttpClient Put/Post Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, httpclient, google-calendar-api

I am trying to perform a PUT to Google Calendar API v3 in order to add an attendee, but every time I get the response 400 BAD REQUEST.  I have simplified it to just attempt to update the max number of attendees to see if it will take, but no dice...

```
        public void AddAttendeeToEvent(string calendarId, string eventId, string attendeeEmail)
        {
        try
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthenticationHelper.Instance.Token);

            var baseUrl = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{0}/events/{1}", calendarId, eventId);
            //var postData = string.Format ("attendees[].email={0}", attendeeEmail);
            var postData = "maxAttendees=100";
            var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = httpClient.PutAsync(baseUrl, content).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string s = "";
        }
    }
```

Note - This is in Xamarin, there is no client library available.  Has to be done manually for now...and the documentation on this is horrible.

Comment: `maxAttendees=100` looks suspicious. Are you sure this shouldn't be in the URL as part of a query string e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{0}/events/{1}?maxAttendees=100`?

Comment: Even if I do:  var response = httpClient.PutAsync(baseUrl, null).Result; it still returns 400: BAD REQUEST

Comment: Doesn't the PUT data need to be JSON?

Comment: switched to json, still same result.  Something else must be wrong.  Can anyone do this in a curl statement?  that would be very helpful.  I have not been able to figure that out either

Answer (score 0):

I propose you drop this code and start over using C# Calendar API client library. You can get it from the downloads in the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

However, as the first step, please read the getting started guidelines and obtain a correct Oauth2 token.